# How to quantify how much data is copied into the GPU in a Theano script?

Tags: python, memory-management, gpu, gpgpu, theano

As a general rule, it's often preferable to avoid to repeatedly copy data from the RAM to the GPU memory, if the data can instead stay in the GPU memory. As a result, some codes store data sets in the GPU memory as a shared variable ([example](https://github.com/yoonkim/CNN_sentence/blob/master/conv_net_sentence.py#L186)).

In Theano, is there any way to quantify how much data is copied into the GPU when a script is executed? My goal is to estimate to what extent not declaring the data set as a shared variable is slowing the program due to copying data from the RAM to the GPU memory. (declaring the data set as a shared variable in the script I am currently profiling would require quite some code changes, so I would prefer to get the estimate before diving into the code).

Comment: So was my response the answer to your problem? Did you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot compute the amount of memory required by a function or script. Assuming you know the number of elements to be stored on a GPU you can easily compute the amount of memory required to store those elements.

A simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
T.config.floatX = 'float32'
dataPoints = np.random.random((5000, 256 * 256)).astype(T.config.floatX)
#float32 data type requires 4 bytes
sizeinGBs = 5000 * 256 * 256 * 4 / 1024. / 1024 / 1024 + (some small over-head constant which we can ignore safely)
```

Which is roughly 1.22 GBs

**UPDATE**

I found the answer to your question. You can easily get the amount of free memory on the GPU using the `CUDA` libray. Below is the code that can help you compute how much GPU memory has been dedicated to a task before and after a function is executed.

```
import theano.sandbox.cuda.basic_ops as sbcuda
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
T.config.floatX = 'float32'
freeGPUMemInGBs = sbcuda.cuda_ndarray.cuda_ndarray.mem_info()[0]/1024./1024/1024
print "Your GPU has %s GBs of free memory" % str(freeGPUMemInGBs)
#An operation is to be executed below
testData = shared(np.random.random((5000, 256 * 256)).astype(T.config.floatX), borrow = True)
print "The tasks above used %s GBs of your GPU memory. The available memory is %s GBs" % (str(freeGPUMemInGBs - sbcuda.cuda_ndarray.cuda_ndarray.mem_info()[0]/1024./1024/1024), str(sbcuda.cuda_ndarray.cuda_ndarray.mem_info()[0]/1024./1024/1024))
```

Then the output (for my machine) is:

```
>>> Your GPU has 11.2557678223 GBs of free memory
>>> The tasks above used 1.22077941895 GBs of your GPU memory. The available memory is 10.0349884033 GBs
```